# Create new tab with button click Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I made a program that creates a new tab with a button click. 
The problem is, that I want to create tab and treeview inside that tab when button is clicked, but I do not know what should I put for root. It always shows this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
import sys

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title(" Program ")                         
myApp.geometry("1000x1200")

tasktabs=ttk.Notebook(myApp)

NewWorkLab=Label(myApp,text="Name: ")
NewWorkLab.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="W", padx=5,pady=5)

NewWorkEntry=Entry(myApp)
NewWorkEntry.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky="W", padx=5,pady=5)

def AddNewWork():

    TabName=NewWorkEntry.get()

    NewWorkTab=ttk.Frame(tasktabs)
    tasktabs.add(NewWorkTab,text=NewWorkEntry.get())

    NewTree= ttk.Treeview(TabName,height=40)
    NewTree['show'] = 'headings'

    NewTree["columns"]=("1","2","3","4","5","6")

    NewTree.column("1", width=20)
    NewTree.column("2", width=320)
    NewTree.column("3", width=40)
    NewTree.column("4", width=80)
    NewTree.column("5", width=80)
    NewTree.column("6", width=80)

    NewTree.heading("1", text="ID")
    NewTree.heading("2", text="Activities")
    NewTree.heading("3", text="Unit")
    NewTree.heading("4", text="Quantity")
    NewTree.heading("5", text="Unit Cost")
    NewTree.heading("6", text="Total Cost")

    NewTree.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=10,padx=0)

AddWorkButton=Button(myApp,text=' Add ', command=AddNewWork)
AddWorkButton.grid(row=0,column=4, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)


tasktabs.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=4,padx=5)   

myApp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember one thing, in Tkinter you cant store any widgets with a variable name ; it has its own way of numbers in which it stores, so if u think u are storing the widget as the name of the value u put in entry box then it is nor correct. It is just a reference to save the variable temporarily,u cant retrieve the value later with the variable name .

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
import sys

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title(" Program ")
myApp.geometry("1000x1200")

tasktabs=ttk.Notebook(myApp)

NewWorkLab=Label(myApp,text="Name: ")
NewWorkLab.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="W", padx=5,pady=5)

NewWorkEntry=Entry(myApp)
NewWorkEntry.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky="W", padx=5,pady=5)

def AddNewWork():


    TabName=ttk.Frame(tasktabs)
    tasktabs.add(TabName,text=NewWorkEntry.get())

    NewTree= ttk.Treeview(TabName,height=40)
    NewTree['show'] = 'headings'

    NewTree["columns"]=("1","2","3","4","5","6")

    NewTree.column("1", width=20)
    NewTree.column("2", width=320)
    NewTree.column("3", width=40)
    NewTree.column("4", width=80)
    NewTree.column("5", width=80)
    NewTree.column("6", width=80)

    NewTree.heading("1", text="ID")
    NewTree.heading("2", text="Activities")
    NewTree.heading("3", text="Unit")
    NewTree.heading("4", text="Quantity")
    NewTree.heading("5", text="Unit Cost")
    NewTree.heading("6", text="Total Cost")

    NewTree.grid(row=2,column=0,pady=10,padx=0)

AddWorkButton=Button(myApp,text=' Add ', command=AddNewWork)
AddWorkButton.grid(row=0,column=4, sticky="W", padx=5, pady=5)


tasktabs.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=4,padx=5)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks my friend. Can I ask you one more question, can you please help me with this?

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50594414/summing-values-from-different-treeviews-tkinter)